# Exoplayer playing m3u8 files Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, m3u8, exoplayer

After trying multiple ways of playing m3u8 files using **videoview and mediaplayer** I decided to give up. Everytime i play the m3u8 file I only hear the voice.(please dont write urls from stack overflow answering my question. I' ve red them all )
Been asking around ,finally got to know that **exoplayer** maybe is the one I'm looking for. However exoplayer seems to be a newbie and I can'n find any proper **tutorial**. That been said Im myself a newbie and all talks about tracker and blabla seem just too complicated for me. I only want to be able to open all my m3u8 files from different urls in my app **without** passing them to vlc or any external intents.

For the record I use KitKat and above. So exoplayer should be implementable.

So what Im desperatly asking for is a **simple tutorial in how I can play my m3u8 files using exoplayer** or anyother way that shows the video and play the audio and **NOT** just one of them. Please dont link me to the exoplayer page on **google dev**. Ive been there too.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Anyone? Help? I would appritiate it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Android 4.1+, you can use this library https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia/ . The example mentioned on the Read-me page should be sufficient to get you started. I have reproduced that code snippet with a few additions/modifications.

```
            private void setupVideoView() {
                EMVideoView emVideoView = (EMVideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_play_activity_video_view);
                emVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);

                //Enter your m3u8 URL below
                emVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://SOMESERVER/playlist.m3u8"));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //Starts the video playback as soon as it is ready
                emVideoView.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPause() {
                super.onPause();
                //Pause Video Playback
                emVideoView.pause();
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

I Have created one demo app to play m3u8 media file

First add gradle dependencies to your file

```
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.0'
```

Create a simple layout file with storage master.m3u8 path as input and  SimpleExoPlayerView view to play downloaded files.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout mlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
  android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/mediaPath"
   android:layout_height="56dp" />
   <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
android:id="@+id/play"
       android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/mediaPath"
       android:background="@color/colorAccent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:text="Play"
android:layout_height="56dp" />
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
   android:layout_below="@+id/play"
   android:id="@+id/video_view"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Create a simple ExoPlayer Activity to play Files.

```
public class ExoPlayer  extends AppCompatActivity{
Context mContext;
SimpleExoPlayerView playerView;
EditText editText;
private ComponentListener componentListener;
private DataSource.Factory mediaDataSourceFactory;
private Handler mainHandler;
private DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector;
SimpleExoPlayer player;
private static final DefaultBandwidthMeter BANDWIDTH_METER = new        DefaultBandwidthMeter();




@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_exoplayer);
   mContext =this;
   editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mediaPath);
   Button btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
   playerView  = (SimpleExoPlayerView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
   mediaDataSourceFactory = buildDataSourceFactory(true);
   mainHandler = new Handler();
   componentListener = new ComponentListener();
   trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();
   btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
      if(editText.getText()!=null && editText.getText().length()>0){
               initializePlayer(editText.getText().toString());
           }
       }
   });
}
   private DataSource.Factory buildDataSourceFactory(boolean useBandwidthMeter) {
   return ((AnalyticsApplication) getApplication())
           .buildDataSourceFactory(useBandwidthMeter ? BANDWIDTH_METER : null);
 }

   private void initializePlayer(String path) {
   player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(mContext, trackSelector);
   player.addListener(componentListener);
//        String path = file:///storage/emulated/0/SugarBox/master.m3u8";
   Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
   MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
   player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
   playerView.setPlayer(player);
 }
  private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
 return new HlsMediaSource(uri, mediaDataSourceFactory, mainHandler, null);
 }
 private void releasePlayer() {
   if (player != null) {
       player.removeListener(componentListener);
       player.release();
       player = null;
   }
   }



 @Override
 public void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
       if(editText.getText()!=null && editText.getText().length()>0){
           initializePlayer(editText.getText().toString());
       }
   }
 }




@Override
   public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   if ((Util.SDK_INT <= 23 || player == null)) {
       if(editText.getText()!=null && editText.getText().length()>0){
           initializePlayer(editText.getText().toString());
       }
   }
 }



@Override
 public void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
   if (Util.SDK_INT <= 23) {
       releasePlayer();
   }
}



 @Override
public void onStop() {
   super.onStop();
   if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
       releasePlayer();
   }
}







   private class ComponentListener implements com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer.EventListener{

   @Override
   public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady,
                                    int playbackState) {
       String stateString;
       switch (playbackState) {
           case com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer.STATE_IDLE:
               stateString = "ExoPlayer.STATE_IDLE      -";
               break;
           case com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING:
               stateString = "ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING -";
               break;
           case com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer.STATE_READY:
               stateString = "ExoPlayer.STATE_READY     -";
               break;
           case com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED:
               stateString = "ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED     -";
               break;
           default:
               stateString = "UNKNOWN_STATE             -";
               break;
       }
       Log.d("ExopLayer", "changed state to " + stateString
               + " playWhenReady: " + playWhenReady);
   }

   @Override
   public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {}
   @Override
   public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups,
                               TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {}
   @Override
   public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {}
   @Override
   public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {}
   @Override
   public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {}
   @Override
   public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {}
  }



private DrmSessionManager<FrameworkMediaCrypto> buildDrmSessionManager(UUID uuid,   String licenseUrl, String[] keyRequestPropertiesArray) throws UnsupportedDrmException {
   if (Util.SDK_INT < 18) {
       return null;
   }
   HttpMediaDrmCallback drmCallback = new HttpMediaDrmCallback(licenseUrl,
           buildHttpDataSourceFactory(false));
   if (keyRequestPropertiesArray != null) {
       for (int i = 0; i < keyRequestPropertiesArray.length - 1; i += 2) {
           drmCallback.setKeyRequestProperty(keyRequestPropertiesArray[i],
                   keyRequestPropertiesArray[i + 1]);
       }
   }
   return new DefaultDrmSessionManager<>(uuid,
           FrameworkMediaDrm.newInstance(uuid), drmCallback, null, mainHandler, null);
 }




  private HttpDataSource.Factory buildHttpDataSourceFactory(boolean useBandwidthMeter) {
   return ((AnalyticsApplication) getApplication())
           .buildHttpDataSourceFactory(useBandwidthMeter ? BANDWIDTH_METER : null);


  }


}
```

Comment: I tried the code but it works only with the file types: m3u8, right?
I tried with the following mp4 file, but nothing happens: https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4

I do not know how to understand so is AnalyticsApplication?
in:
return ((AnalyticsApplication) getApplication ())
            .buildHttpDataSourceFactory (useBandwidthMeter? BANDWIDTH_METER: null);

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way to stream m3u8 files using ExoPlayer Lib hope to help
https://github.com/karim23/SimpleStreamPlayer/tree/master

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = getApplicationContext();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //change the live streaming URL with yours. 
    contentUri = "http://abclive.abcnews.com/i/abc_live4@136330/index_1200_av-b.m3u8?sd=10&b=1200&rebase=on";
    // contentType = DemoUtil.TYPE_HLS;
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, VideoPlayerActivity.class).setData(Uri.parse(contentUri))
            .putExtra(VideoPlayerActivity.CONTENT_ID_EXTRA, -1)
            //Change the type according to the live streaming extension.
            .putExtra(VideoPlayerActivity.CONTENT_TYPE_EXTRA, DemoUtil.TYPE_HLS);
    liveStreamingTv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainActivity_liveStreamingTv);
    liveStreamingTv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with m3u8 with following code

```
    videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoViewXml);

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();

    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(VIDEO_PATH));
    videoView.start();

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no tutorials on `ExoPlayer` right now. `ExoPlayer` is a the best alternative to `MediaPlayer` but is not very newbie friendly at the moment.

What you have to do is go to the github page and take a look at the `DemoPlayer` class in the `demo` app.

This app can open a lot of different formats including `hls`.

Comment: How do i use the demo? Do i need to copy the code into my app?

Answer (score 0):

Solving the issue of Black screen when playing m3u8 file, I have solved it using this,

> implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.13.3'

Media source code:

```
    private fun buildMediaSource(uri: Uri): MediaSource {
    
            val userAgent = "exoplayer-codelab"
    
            return if (uri.lastPathSegment!!.contains("mp3") || uri.lastPathSegment!!.contains("mp4")) {
                ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent))
                    .createMediaSource(uri)
            } else {
                HlsMediaSource.Factory(DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent))
                    .createMediaSource(uri)
            }
}
```

**MediaSource:**

```
 val mediaSource = buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(stories[counter].mediaUrl))
 simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource, false, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataSource.Factory fdataSourceFactory = new FileDataSource.Factory();
DataSource.Factory ddataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory();
if (urlAll.startsWith("http") ) {
  // Create a HLS media source pointing to a playlist uri.
  MediaSource hlsMediaSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(ddataSourceFactory)
                                    .setAllowChunklessPreparation(false)
                                    .createMediaSource(mediaItem);
  player.addMediaSource(index, hlsMediaSource);
}
else {
  // Create a HLS media source pointing to a playlist uri.
  MediaSource hlsMediaSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(fdataSourceFactory)
                                    .setAllowChunklessPreparation(false)
                                    .createMediaSource(mediaItem);
  player.addMediaSource(index, hlsMediaSource);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).