# ExoPlayer in Android TV using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-tv, m3u8, exoplayer

How can I use ExoPlayer library to stream m3u8 files and play it on Android TV.
I just want to build a basic Video Player to play m3u8 files on Android TV.

The library I am using is this : [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

Answer (score 0):

Use the  emVideoView.setVideoURI from the [ExoMedia Sample](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia/)

```
private VideoView videoView;

private void setupVideoView() {
    // Make sure to use the correct VideoView import
    videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);

    //For now we just picked an arbitrary item to play
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("https://archive.org/download/Popeye_forPresident/Popeye_forPresident_512kb.mp4"));
}

@Override
public void onPrepared() {
    //Starts the video playback as soon as it is ready
    videoView.start();
}
```

Additional reference, [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418140/exoplayer-playing-m3u8-files-android).