# Is there is any flutter plugin to play live streaming video (.m3u8) in android?

Tags: android, flutter, live-streaming

I have used `video_player: ^0.10.1+2` it's working fine in IOS but not working on Android

```dart
_videoPlayerController1 = VideoPlayerController.network('url with .m3u8 file');
  

_chewieController = ChewieController(
    videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController1,
    //aspectRatio: 3 / 2,
    //aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController1.value.aspectRatio,
    autoPlay: true,
    looping: true,
    routePageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondAnimation, provider) {
      return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: animation,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return VideoScaffold(
            child: Scaffold(
              resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
              body: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.black,
                child: provider,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    },
    materialProgressColors: ChewieProgressColors(
       playedColor: Colors.red,
       handleColor: Colors.blue,
       backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
       bufferedColor: Colors.lightGreen,
     ),
     placeholder: Container(
       color: Colors.grey,
     ),
     autoInitialize: true,
    );
```

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13111): com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 404
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13111):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:300)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13111):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:83)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13111):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13111):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.open(DataSourceInputStream.java:65)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13111):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:156)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13111):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:381)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13111):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13111):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(13111):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418140/exoplayer-playing-m3u8-files-android

Comment: Thank @VidorVistrom,
This is for native android but i need solution in flutter

Comment: For flutter you could do either of the following, 1st, create a webview and use browser for playing files, 2nd, create a platform channel for your own use :)

Comment: @NikunjRami, I personally check with flutter plugin of `video_player` and its working fine for HLS .m3u8 file.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter's [`video_player`](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) plugin uses ExoPlayer on Android as mentioned in the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/play-video). It should have support for .m3u8 format per checking [ExoPlayer's GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues?q=is%3Aclosed%20m3u8%20).

If you're able to run an Android project, I suggest trying to play your .m3u8 stream link on their [demo app](https://exoplayer.dev/demo-application.html) and see if it works. If the .m3u8 link does work on the ExoPlayer demo app, there could be an issue in the `video_player` plugin. Otherwise, I suggest filing a ticket on [ExoPlayer's GitHub issue page](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues) to check if there's an issue in the media that you're using. Please also include an accessible .m3u8 stream link that can be tested to diagnose the issue.